# Send or Send across

Tags: differences, meaning-in-context

How the words **send** and **send across** are used in email writing context? What are difference between these two?

> You can send your profile to 123@abc.com.

**Or**

> You can send across your profiles to 123@abc.com.

In the above two sentence what is the key difference?

Comment: "Send across" is something of an affectation that some people use.  "Across" is just noise in that context.

Answer (score 4):

They're entirely interchangeable.

Both ***send across*** and ***send on over*** are common colloquialisms which don't change the meaning of ***send*** at all, but which are used to convey familiarity and/or friendliness.

It's likely that the author is not even really aware of using one over the other, so I wouldn't read too much into the differences between them.

Comment: I've never heard _send across_ used like this. Is it a Britishism?

Comment: I don't think so. I think it's just a habitual phrase some people use and most don't, that doesn't actually mean anything special.

Comment: If anything, an Americanism, I think.

Comment: I think that "convey familiarity and/or friendliness" is the key here - it's the sort of language which is often described as "down home", meaning unpretentious, welcoming and friendly (and often ungrammatical).

Answer (score -1):

It is used when you are sending something like picture through emails to someone, then someone may say i will send the pictures across to you.